How can I group the attributes of xmltodict output in a subdictionary?
Basically, I'm trying to create a subdictionary or sublist specific for the attributes of the output generated by xmltodict. For example:
For the following XML:
print(json.dumps(xmltodict.parse("""
...  <mydocument has="an attribute" also="another attribute">
...    <and>
...      <many>elements</many>
...      <many>more elements</many>
...    </and>
...    <plus a="complex">
...      element as well
...    </plus>
...  </mydocument>
...  """), indent=4))

The xmlodict default output is:
{
    "mydocument": {
        "@has": "an attribute", 
        "@also": "an attribute",
        "and": {
            "many": [
                "elements", 
                "more elements"
            ]
        }, 
        "plus": {
            "@a": "complex", 
            "#text": "element as well"
        }
    }
}

And I´d like to group all the attributes as showed below:
{
    "mydocument": {
        "Attributes": {"@has": "an attribute", "@also": "another attribute"}, 
        "and": {
            "many": [
                "elements", 
                "more elements"
            ]
        }, 
        "plus": {
            "Attributes": {"@a": "complex"}, 
            "#text": "element as well"
        }
    }
}

I was trying to code something that detects and group all the dictionary keys starting with '@', but my loop can´t handle this recursively through all the tags.
